# Dystopian story about lower students randomly culled

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find the name of a short story from (probably) the 70's or 80's.  Most likely in Analog or Asimov's Science Fiction.  It was about a student in a school.  If he tested high enough, he was exempt from the end of year random killing.  The protagonist lets his grades fall, and is put in the random killing.  He has figured out a pattern to the killings, and tells his friend what position to be in when entering the machine.  Alas, he was wrong in his assumption as to the order...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a 2016 movie called The Thinning (Starring Logan Paul and Peyton List). If I recall correctly it's based off a book but I have no idea what it's called. It is about a couple of kids in a dystopia where they take a test and the kids who scored low get killed by the government. I forget exactly how it plays out but might be a start.

Comment: It’d be a good idea to add some details about the movie to explain why the description might match the one in the question.

Comment: The movie is what made me recall the story.  It IS similar, but not the same...

Comment: From a quick check, I do not see anything saying this was based off a book or short story. So I presume it was based off an original script.